# SUMIF equivalent in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table similar to this:

```
Invoice Item Batch Quantity
12345   ABCD A1    50
12345   ABCD A2    150
```

I need a SQL function that will give me those 2 new columns (with all the same line items, not a simple GROUPBY with a SUM)

```
Invoice Item Batch Quantity Tot inv Qty %Inv
12345   ABCD A1    50       200         25%
12345   ABCD A2    150      200         75%
```

Not sure if I need to use CASE with GROUPBY or if there's a function like SUMIF in Excel...

I've tried SUM with GROUP BY but lost my details

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output as plain text, not as images

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Which database are you using (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, ...) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the followinhg solution.

**T-SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (Invoice INT, Item VARCHAR(20), Batch CHAR(2), Quantity INT);
INSERT @tbl (Invoice, Item, Batch, Quantity) VALUES
(12345, 'ABCD', 'A1', 50),
(12345, 'ABCD', 'A2', 150);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.* 
    , SUM(Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY Invoice) AS Total_Invoce_Qty
    , TRY_CAST(TRY_CAST(Quantity AS DECIMAL(10,2)) / SUM(Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY Invoice) * 100 AS INT) AS [%Inv]
FROM @tbl AS t
```

**Output**

| Invoice | Item | Batch | Quantity | Total_Invoce_Qty | %Inv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | ABCD | A1 | 50 | 200 | 25 |
| 12345 | ABCD | A2 | 150 | 200 | 75 |

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify which database you use, but - it *smells* like analytic functions should be involved; they are *designed* for such purposes.

This is Oracle; see whether something similar is supported in your database:

```
select invoice, item, batch, quantity,
  sum(quantity) over () total,
  ratio_to_report(quantity) over () * 100 percent
from test;

   INVOICE ITEM BATCH    QUANTITY      TOTAL    PERCENT
---------- ---- ------ ---------- ---------- ----------
     12345 ABCD A1             50        200         25
     12345 ABCD A2            150        200         75
```